# Adobe Scene7 BasicZoomViewer: How to change max zoom resolution

Tags: adobe, scene7

I'm using [Adobe Scene7 BasicZoomViewer](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/s7/viewers_ref/c_html5_20_basic_zoom_viewer_about.html) and I'm trying to adjust the max zoom resolution but nothing I'm trying has worked.

[The docs definitely suggest this should be possible](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/s7/viewers_ref/r_html5_basic_zoom_viewer_20_config_attrib_zoomview_zoomstep.html) but like I said, so far nothing has worked.

## Small example of what I've tried

```js
        var s7BasicZoomViewer = new s7viewers.BasicZoomViewer({
          containerId: 's7viewer-' + iterator,
          params: {
            asset: assetUrl,
            serverurl: serverUrl
          },
          handlers: {
            initComplete: function () {
              var zoomView = s7BasicZoomViewer.getComponent('zoomView')

              // ive tried passing an object
              zoomView.zoomStep = { step: 3, limit: 5 }

              // ive tried directly setting it on the "zoomView" just like the docs suggest
              zoomView.zoomStep = 2,5
            }
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust the **zoomstep** you need to insert a **zoomstep** property to the **BasicZoomViewer** constructor config object.

```js
var s7BasicZoomViewer = new s7viewers.BasicZoomViewer({
  containerId: 's7viewer-' + iterator,
  params: {
    asset: assetUrl,
    serverurl: serverUrl,
    zoomstep: '1,1'  // set the zoomstep property
  }
})
```

This also goes for all of the [Config Properties](https://marketing.adobe.com/resources/help/en_US/s7/viewers_ref/r_html5_basic_zoom_viewer_20_config_attrib.html) mentioned in the docs.

### Note

These config properties can also be placed on the URL of the page instead of the Viewers config object.

Example: https://example.com?zoomstep=1,1 would achieve the same goal as placing the **zoomstep** on the config object.